# Кодирование признаков

Tags: python, pandas, машинное-обучение, scikit-learn

Необходимо реализовать Kfold схему с пятью фолдами.
Разбить данные на 5 фолдов и проитерироваться по ним: по 4 обучающих фолда для подсчета средних значений таргета по item_id и этими значениями необходимо заполнить валидационный фолд на каждой итерации.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'item_id': [19, 27, 28, 29, 32],
                   'target': [0.0, 0.0, 6.0, 3.0, 1.0],
                  'item_target_enc': [0.0222, 0.056834, 0.141176, 0.037383, 1.319042]})
```

```
# You will need to compute correlation like that
corr = np.corrcoef(all_data['target'].values, encoded_feature)[0][1]
print(corr)
```

Ожидаемы ответ: 0.4165

Как это можно реализовать с помощью функции map?

Спасибо!

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста суть вопроса. Вопрос в том как проитерироваться по фолдам?

Comment: Да, именно это мне непонятно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пример из [документации](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
>>> X = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2], [3, 4]])
>>> y = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> kf = KFold(n_splits=2)
>>> kf.get_n_splits(X)
2
>>> print(kf)
KFold(n_splits=2, random_state=None, shuffle=False)
>>> for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X):
...     print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
...     X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
...     y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
TRAIN: [2 3] TEST: [0 1]
TRAIN: [0 1] TEST: [2 3]
```

Comment: Там в вопросе ещё что-то про **target encoding**, а не просто про фолды, но может я ошибаюсь и правда вопрос просто про `KFold`. Вопрос так сформулирован, что я мозг сломал )

Comment: Да, код добавлен про это теперь

Comment: @Panda _код добавлен про это теперь_, пожалуйста, не изменяйте вопрос после того, как вам дали ответ.  Если ваша задача не решена в полном объёме, то отметьте ответ как принятый и задайте новый вопрос, можете сослаться на текущий как на взаимосвязанный.